# How to construct a parameterized class literal from two existing class literals?

Tags: java, class, generics, literals

I'd wonder, if and how it is possible to achieve the below, while only beeing able to use the two class literal variables:

```
Class<Foo<Bar>> getFoobar(){

    Class<Foo> fooClass = Foo.class;
    Class<Bar> barClass = Bar.class;

    // ... combine and return Class<Foo<Bar>>
}
```

... with the restriction, that it is not possible to use the types literally, but ok to retrieve the types programmatically from the class literal variables.

Comment: If I've understood you correctly then no I don't think this would be possible because you're trying to return a type which doesn't really exist... There is no Class of type <Foo<Bar>> because that information is bound dynamically. Not 100% certain though.

Comment: ...so to clarify, are we assuming that you have a class `Foo` whose generic type is `Bar`, and you're after a `Class` which contains the respective types of `Foo` and `Bar`?

Comment: @JSmith yes, you are right.

Comment: @MartinPeter Why you want to do that... can you add to the question of the code where you need such a thing?

Comment: What are you going to do with this `Class<Foo<Bar>>`? That will determine what you should use.

Answer (score 1):

We can not use type parameters (as you have correctly noticed) literally i.e. we can't expect that expressions like `T.class` or `new T()` will work, because we can't do much with generic types "programmatically". Parametrized types lose their type parameters after compilation, thus for the following instance of `Foo<T>` type:

```
Foo<String> foostr...;
Foo<Bar> foobar...;
```

we will have the same `Class` object, i.e.

```
foostr.getClass() == foobar.getClass() == Foo.class
```

consequently there is no point in permitting class literals such as `Foo<String>.class` or `Foo<Bar>.class`.

This is the reason behind many limitations of generic types at compile type: since there is no information about type arguments at runtime (because of *type erasure*) we have to limit much of possibilities at compile time.

**One possibility** to work with generic types at runtime is extracting the information about the class `Foo` and its type argument `Bar` as a `ParameterizedType` object, e.g.

```
class Bar {
  ...
}

class Foo<T> {
  ...
}

class Foobar extends Foo<Bar> {

  ParameterizedType getFoobar() {
    return (ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
  }
}

...

Foobar foobar = new Foobar();
System.out.println(foobar.getFoobar().getRawType()); // Foo.class
System.out.println(foobar.getFoobar().getActualTypeArguments()[0]); // Bar.class
```

**Another approach** which is based on the first one, but is easier to implement, is the usage of `TypeReference` (or create your own class) from FasterXML Jacson Project to capture the parametrized type:

```
class Foo<T> { ... }

class Bar { ... }

TypeReference typeReference = new TypeReference<Foo<Bar>>() {};  
ParameterizedTypeImpl parametrizedType = (ParameterizedTypeImpl) typeReference.getType();
System.out.println(parametrizedType.getTypeName()); // Foo<Bar>
System.out.println(parametrizedType.getRawType()); // Foo
System.out.println(parametrizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]); // Bar
```

Just look at the implementation of `ParameterizedTypeImpl#toString()` method for details.